# Is it possible to send email from the phone without user interaction?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to make an application that takes a photo and send it to the email you have registered with. I want the photo to be sent directly to the email without any user interaction. Is this possible? Can I use the parse database to do this?

Comment: I am not sure from parse but you can write your own backend implementation and make a http post request to your server. eg. test.com/info.php?param=data.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Can you provide a link with a tutorial or an example using that

Comment: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124) for some inspiration on how to do it using the JavaMail API. You could also use a 3rd party services like [Mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com).